# Curvature (Gaussian) of a hypersphere

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I am looking for a general formula for the Gaussian curvature of an $n$-sphere (the set of points in $R^{n+1}$ equidistant from the origin) of radius $r$.

From what I have read, there would be $n$ principal curvatures to consider, but since this space is so simple, I was hoping there would be a great deal of simplification. For a circle, the Gaussian curvature is $1/r$ and for a sphere it is $1/r^2$, but it seems too simple for it to be $1/r^n$ for $S^n$. However if it is indeed so, I would gladly welcome any sources, or just pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Do you know that for $S^2$?

Comment: @BabakS. I got that from [this Mathworld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianCurvature.html), specifically equation 14 and one of the last paragraphs on the page, although the used values $R_1,R_2$, and $a$ are not explicitly defined (but I assume them to be the radii in each of two directions, and the radius of the sphere, respectively).

Comment: See this [corollary 4.8](http://books.google.com/books?id=U19EgdcSQckC&pg=PA394&lpg=PA394&dq=gaussian+curvature+for+n-sphere+boothby&source=bl&ots=JsBfhCa_3M&sig=T-7wiIPxvzVNpEqWjdalU8JcOB8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YUWBUb6VJa2t4AOywYGICQ&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=gaussian%20curvature%20for%20n-sphere%20boothby&f=false)

Comment: @BabakS.I see now - my question is wrong, as Gauss curvature applies to 2-dimensional surfaces, and its higher-dimensional analog is sectional curvature, which is indeed $1/r^2$ at every point.

Comment: I am glad i could help. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Your original hunch is correct. Gaussian curvature does make sense for a hypersurface, whereas for a general Riemannian manifold the curvature tensor and sectional curvature are appropriate. For a hypersurface $X$ in $\mathbb R^n$, the Gaussian curvature is the Jacobian of the Gauss map $\nu\colon X\to S^n$. For a sphere of radius $r$, we have $\nu(x) = x/r$, whose derivative is $1/r$ times the identity map. Thus, the determinant is indeed $1/r^n$.