# Curvature of the hypersphere as dimension grows

Tags: differential-geometry

I am curious about how to think of the curvature of hyperspheres $S^n \in R^{n+1}$ with a constant radius  $r$ as the dimension $n$ increases. The counterintuitive result that the surface area (and volume) of a hypersphere [quickly goes to zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere) and leads to a "spiky" picture, albeit with the usual properties of a sphere left intact, is well known. Likewise, the surface area contained by a given hyper-spherical cap also shrinks exponentially fast, seemingly supporting this spiky conclusion. To me this indicates that the curvature at any point of the hypersphere should reflect this and have some kind of exponential dependence on the dimension as well as the radius.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378363/curvature-gaussian-of-a-hypersphere) seems to indicate that for such a well behaved surface there is a natural extension of the Gaussian curvature in $n$ dimensions which shows that the curvature is exponential in the dimension, calculated via the Jacobian of the Gauss map which is simply $g(x) = x/r$ for a point $x$ on the hypersphere and so a Gaussian curvature of $1/r^n$. But in the same page one can also consider the sectional curvature for general Riemannian manifolds which seems to be much more commonly used and is always the curvature of the hypersphere with respect to a 2-dimensional subspace of the tangent space - coinciding always with the spherical Gaussian case and so is $1/r^2$ for a hypersphere of any dimension.

Thus my question - which of these is the better way to think of this and how might I reconcile the sectional curvature with this idea of a spiky sphere? Is it simply a case of what intuition I have left for hyperspheres further collapsing for such objects?

Comment: Very qualitatively: the curvature in any single direction stays the same, but as $n$ grows, there are more and more independent directions.

Comment: @Kajelad, could you give a rough idea of what that implies geometrically, if anything?

Comment: Roughly speaking, some geometric objects, such as Ricci/Scalar curvature, involve a sum or product over an orthonormal basis, and as a result will have an interesting dependence on dimension. Others, such as principal/sectional curvature, only care about individual 1 or 2 dimensional subspaces, and so they won't "notice" the extra dimensions, as long as the behavior in each such subspace remains the same.